# SQL UNION with Where clause a result of the first select

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT (COL1,COL2, ClientID)
FROM Jobs
Union
SELECT (ClientID,COL2,COL3)
FROM Clients WHERE (the ClientID= ClientID my first select)
```

I'm really stuck, I've been trying joins and unions and have no idea how to do this.

**EDIT**Query to create jobs table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `JobID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Trade` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SubTrade` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `Urgency` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `DatePosted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Photo` longblob,
  `Photo2` longblob,
  `Address` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `ShowAddress` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `ShowExact` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `JobStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `ClientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TradesmanID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=171 ;
```

and query to create clients table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients` (
  `ClientID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `HomePhone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `County` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `NotificationID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=96 ;
```

Comment: What result do you want to achive? You can create examples using sqlfiddle

Comment: Can you provide bit more data as to what the query should do..what is the expected output..

Comment: Will JOINs not work in your situation?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I need to get a clients name, email, mobile where their clientID is also associated with a job in a jobs table. I've no experience with sqlfiddle

Comment: If you have no experience yet, you will have it afterwards. It will enable us to understand your table structure and learn what you need so we can create a query that produces this result

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name phpmyadmin

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer the query to make those two tables is now in the question. Please any help if you can. I just found this bug but have too upload to the store within a couple hours

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
Clients.ClientID
,Clients.NotificationID
,Clients.Email
,Clients.Mobile
,Clients.HomePhone 
,Jobs.JobID
,Jobs.Title
,Jobs.Trade
,Jobs.Address               AS JobAddress
,Jobs.Urgency
,Jobs.DatePosted
,Jobs.Description
,Jobs.Photo
,Jobs.Photo2
,Jobs.ShowAddress
,Jobs.ShowExact
,Jobs.JobStatus
    ,Jobs.TradesmanID
    ,Jobs.Longitude
    ,Jobs.Latitude

 FROM
    Clients
 INNER JOIN 
    Jobs
        on Clients.ClientId = Jobs.ClientId
```

Comment: apologies, misread tthe answer, I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: Based off your answer, my query was as follows: SELECT Clients.ClientID,Clients.NotificationID,Clients.Email, Clients.Mobile, Clients.HomePhone
INNER JOIN (SELECT (JobID, Title, Trade, Address, Urgency, DatePosted, Description, Photo, Photo2, ShowAddress, ShowExact, Address, JobStatus, TradesmanID,  Longitude, Latitude, ClientID)
FROM Jobs) AS A
on Clients.ClientId = A.ClientId
FROM Clients. This is returning an sql syntax error

Comment: we have a few different answers to do with different types of databases. Do you know which one you are using? Need to know this before I advise.

Comment: @Sarin I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you want the jobs info in the final answer?

Comment: yes, everything from jobs and 4 columns from clients which is based of  the linking column clientID existing in both

Comment: @Anthony Horne thank you so much. Very helpful! Now  I need to slot these into even bigger queries

Comment: Pleasure.  Take a note of Ali's CTE query.  They are super useful when the concept finally "clicks"

Comment: @AnthonyHorne the only difference from this to my original query was that I had from Job INNER JOIN Clients i.e. the other way around and it didn't work in all cases. Will do re cte

Answer (score 1):

How about this? There is a bit of duplication i.e. the select clause in the second union replications the first statement but it will work.

```
SELECT COL1,COL2, ClientID
FROM Jobs
Union
SELECT ClientID,COL2,COL3
FROM Clients WHERE (Select ClientID FROM Jobs)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Srin, this is however returning 'The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns'

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the columns in one of your select statements? double check them? What database are you using?

Comment: @Sarain is it to do with the where clause not comparing anythinng?

Comment: @user2363025 not my area of expertise, sorry! The statement looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     SELECT c.ClientID, c.COL2, c.COL3, x.col1
        FROM Clients c inner join 
                         (select clientId, 
                                 min(col1) as col1 
                          from jobs 
                          group by clientId) x
           on c.clientId = x.clientId
```

Comment: Standard SQL needs the statement termination character (the `;`) at the **end** of the statement, not at the beginning.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I see, but as I wrote a code for sql-server and using CTE, it is the style and syntax of this command

Comment: No it's not the "*syntax of this command*" - that's a great misconception. You just make sure the **previous** statement is terminated correctly. You might want to read this:  https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: Yeah, you are right, in some ways. Thanks for your hint :)